# ASP.NET Eval ToString Format Currency Culture Specifying

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I specify the currency format, for example *tr-TR*?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Fiyat"))%>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Format_System_IFormatProvider_System_String_System_Object___)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<%# String.Format( new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:C}", Eval("Fiyat") %>
```